# What is the opposite of a prodigy?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, antonyms

I'm looking for a single word, or a succinct phrase to describe an artist that achieves greatness after a lot of hard work and repeated failures, rather than someone who was naturally talented.

The closest equivalent I could think of was Journeyman, but that doesn't have the connotations of achieving greatness. Is there a better word to describe such an artist?

Comment: This is just the normal case of most people with expertise at something, it's not clear it warrants a special word. Prodigies are the exceptions.

Comment: For many people, the opposite of _prodigy_ is _progidy_; it's not easy to say all those stop clusters fast.

Comment: Progidy seems to be defined as people who think they are prodigy's but aren't, the person in question is very humble in nature, so I don't think this term applies. Thanks for your reply though.

Comment: @JohnLawler "What seems to be the problem,  Ociffer? Yes, it's a one way street but I was only going one way"

Comment: @AdiMG That's mostly a joke definition.

Comment: The word, extending your guild-theme, is ***master***. As in *master painter*, *master chef*, *chessmaster*, *the Dutch Masters*, and so on. A journeyman is exactly the person who's pretty good at something but hasn't *mastered* it yet (the old guild system went *apprentice* -> *journeyman* -> *master*, which happened after the journeyman became sufficiently experienced to produce his *masterpiece*, the medieval analog of a *master's thesis* or *doctoral thesis* or that thing the art kids have to do to graduate).

Comment: Consider "accomplished artist".

Comment: Nothing's coming to me, not even a succinct phrase.

Comment: Single adjective: hardworking.  Phrase: Name-of-Person has paid his dues.

Comment: Hmmm...  How is it that no one has suggested "condigy"?

Comment: Slightly more seriously, I have read "yeoman" used to come close to this meaning, presumably borrowing on the definition "one that performs great and loyal service"

Comment: *achieves greatness [only] after a lot of hard work and repeated failures* describes a (successful) *plodder*.

Comment: I'll note that you're talking about someone who *perseveres*.

Answer (score 1):

Dan Bron wrote in a comment:

> The word, extending your guild-theme, is ***master***. As in *master painter*, *master chef*, *chessmaster*, *the Dutch Masters*, and so on. A journeyman is exactly the person who's pretty good at something but hasn't *mastered* it yet (the old guild system went *apprentice* -> *journeyman* -> *master*, which happened after the journeyman became sufficiently experienced to produce his *masterpiece*, the medieval analog of a *master's thesis* or *doctoral thesis* or that thing the art kids have to do to graduate).